# Why the Sets have keys equals to values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, set, key

The book

> Understanding ECMAScript 6

states that

> **Sets don’t have keys, however.** The people behind the ECMAScript 6
>   standard could have made the callback function in the set version of forEach()
>   accept two arguments, but that would have made it different from the other
>   two. Instead, they found a way to keep the callback function the same and
>   accept three arguments: **each value in a set is considered to be the key and
>   the value.** As such, the frst and second argument are always the same in
>   forEach() on sets to keep this functionality consistent with the other forEach()
>   methods on arrays and maps.

why not to make keys as in Arrays?
what is a motive behind that?

Comment: Because you can't access sets by key, so it would be a useless parameter.

Comment: why not to make sets to be accessable by keys? Why keys in sets don't work as in arrays?

Comment: Because sets don't have any order, so there's nothing useful to use as the key. Sets are more like objects with keys but no values.

Comment: In effect, the key and value are equivalent. That's why `forEach()` just passes the value as both parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some sense, `Set`s actually do have indices, if not keys..

Logically, a set would not even have a defined iteration order, never mind keys.  But the fact is, iteration of `new Set([1, 2, 3])` is ordered differently from `new Set([3, 1, 2])`.

This is the difference between mathematics and programming.

---

**Update**: Question updated with discussion from comments

---

The key/index really shouldn't exist. If there was a reasonable way to avoid even having it, I think they would have. But in programming we can't just say "for all `s` in set `S`..." We need to be able to iterate over those `s`'s. But we shouldn't look for any more than this iteration. As much as possible, `new Set([1, 2, 3])` and `new Set([3, 1, 2])` should act as much alike as possible.

Imagine if we serialized a Trie to store the set `{'baby', 'bad', 'bank', 'box', 'dad', 'dance'}` as `(b(a(b(y)dn(k))o(x))d(a(dn(c(e)))))`. That has no indices at all. The only reason that these are supplied is to keep `forEach` as consistent as possible across the various types. Set doesn't fit as well as others.  That's all.

In other words, it makes more sense to reuse the value (or alternatively to consistently pass some irrelevant token) than to pretend the iteration indices are meaningful parts of the `Set` interface.  Ordering is accidental, implementation details, necessary since programmers cannot use mathematical techniques. But it is not part of the essential interface of `Set`s.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Scott. I understood that keys and values of Sets are the same to keep `forEach` consistent. But here is another question. Why Sets are supposed to be unordered?

Comment: Again, this goes back to mathematics.  Mathematical sets are simply collections of elements.  The only logical question you can ask about a set is whether it contains a specific element.  For programming purposes, we need to also include the ability to add, remove, and list elements, but none of those are fundamental to the notion of a `Set`.

We already have ordered collections, *arrays*, so there is no reason to duplicate this in a new type. 

Some languages, by the way, insist that their sets be iterated in *random* order, just to make sure no one depends on an accidental ordering.